# Preserve non-html tags while parsing the HTML string

Tags: java, grails, groovy, jsoup, gsp

I have been working in a project where the user need feature to parse the HTML data saved in the Database. I have used `<div>` and JSOUP to parse the value into HTML for eg:- `<b>"Test"</b>` . It works correctly to display - **"Test"** that text in that particular HTML format. But the problem arises when the text inside the tags get removed. For eg when I have angle bracket < > the text gets escaped in from the JSOUP `<b>"Test 1 s< a test test 1<,tasa>"</b>`

I get result

**" Test 1 s**

The other text gets removed. I need to display whole

**"Test 1 s< a test test 1<,tasa>".**

Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
def html = URLDecoder.decode(testValue.getAt('Test').replaceAll("%(?![0-9a-fA-F]{2})", "%25"),"UTF-8")
Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.basic())
```

Comment: The requirements aren't entirely clear.  How do you want to handle something like `<b>How should <foo>this</foo> behave</b>`?

Comment: according to html rules `<` must be represented as `&lt;` if it's a text and not the beginning of a tag

Comment: @JeffScottBrown in short i want the non-html tags to be avoided during html parsing. Jsoup functionality seems to be removing any tags occurrences if not mentioned in white list. If there are any other such property in jsoup it would be great but i couldn't find any so would be really helpful if i get any such method to parse the only html tags avoiding the other non-html tags like the angle brackets and such.

Comment: @daggett yes, but using regex to replace all such occurrences seems to be quite tiresome and faulty.

Comment: what you are trying to do with replaceAll?

Comment: "in short i want the non-html tags to be avoided during html parsing" - It isn't clear what a `non-html` tag is.  For something like `<b>How should <foo>this</foo> behave</b>`, both `foo` and `b` are html tags.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown yes want to prevent <foo> from getting erased.

Comment: @daggett used for decoding stuffs

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED** according to comments to support one level of nested elements

to support recursive nested elements code must be reviewed

groovy:

```
@Grab(group='org.jsoup', module='jsoup', version='1.11.3')
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode

def html = '''
<html>
<title>my title</title>
<body>
<b>Test 1 s< a test test 1<,tasa> <foo>this</foo> zzz</b>
</body>
</html>'''

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html)
def txt = doc.select('html body b').first()?.childNodes()
             .collect{e-> e instanceof TextNode ? e.text() : e.toString() }.join()

println txt
```

prints

```
Test 1 s< a test test 1<,tasa> <foo>
 this
</foo> zzz
```

Comment: In a comment above, @noobCoder indicated that they want to prevent `<foo>` from being erased with input like `<b>How should <foo>this</foo> behave</b>`.  The solution above doesn't account for that.

Comment: FYI... This answer has been changed since I left my previous comment.

Comment: right. like a comment under the question )

Comment: "right. like a comment under the question" - My comment was for the benefit of readers later as my claim was made incorrect by the edit.  I wasn't criticizing the edit.

Comment: updated the answer to be clear. i hope people understand that all goes unsync in this world )

Comment: @daggett thank you so much for the solution, I am actually away from my PC. So i need to add on the tags i need to render as HTML document like.  ```doc.select('html body b href a p code pre')``` right ? and will it work with the attributes like ```style``` added ?